# Why my pure NIO selectKey still has event selected

Tags: java, nio

I am a NIO beginner.

Suppose I have a NIO server like:

```
package org.example.nio.selectordemo2;

import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class NIOServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        Selector selector = Selector.open();
        serverSocketChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(6666));
        serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        serverSocketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
        int loopCount = 0;
        while (true) {
            if (++loopCount == 20) break;
            if(selector.select(2000) == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            Set<SelectionKey> selectionKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
            Iterator<SelectionKey> keyIterator = selectionKeys.iterator();
            while (keyIterator.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = keyIterator.next();
                if(key.isAcceptable()) {
                    SocketChannel socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
                    socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
                    socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ, ByteBuffer.allocate(1024));
                }
                if(key.isReadable()) {
                    SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel)key.channel();
                    ByteBuffer buffer = (ByteBuffer)key.attachment();
                    channel.read(buffer);
                    System.out.println("Receive message:" + new String(buffer.array()));
                }
                keyIterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I will run above server code first, and then run the below client code. Suppose that the server code will receive two event, one is for connect, one is for read message. So suppose the server will run finish once the client connect and send message. However, the result is, it seems like the server keep notified the same event.

```
package org.example.nio.selectordemo2;

import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;

public class NIOClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
        socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        InetSocketAddress inetSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 6666);
        if (!socketChannel.connect(inetSocketAddress)) {
            while (!socketChannel.finishConnect()) {
                System.out.println("Doing other job");
            }
        }
        String str = "Sending A Message....";
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(str.getBytes());
        socketChannel.write(buffer);
    }
}
```

However, what make me strange is, the result keep like:
[image]

Obviously the problem is in

```
Set<SelectionKey> selectionKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
```

But I don't know why, or how I should handler.

Comment: You are not using ByteBuffer correctly.  You need to [clear](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#clear%28%29) it before passing it to channel.read, and you need to [flip](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#flip%28%29) it after the read and then [decode](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#decode%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%29) it to a String, rather than reading the underlying array.

Comment: hi @VGR, thank you for your command, Accoring to my understanding, socketChannel.write() only accept the parameter bytebuffer, so I can not clear it before passing it to channel read. and so there is no meaning to decode it to a string. Or would you write down your code accordingly for my reference?

Comment: socketChannel.write() has nothing to do with this.  I’m talking about doing `buffer.clear();` before you call `channel.read(buffer);`.  The first time you execute channel.read, the buffer’s position will be moved;  you may not have room in your buffer after that, unless you clear it before subsequent reads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the [documentation for the Buffer class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/Buffer.html), which is the superclass of ByteBuffer.  You are completely ignoring one of the most important properties of all buffers:  the [position](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/Buffer.html#position%28%29).

Each Buffer, including ByteBuffers, maintains a position.  A position is an index within the ByteBuffer which is determines where data will be added to the buffer, and also where in the buffer data is read from.

When you call `channel.read(buffer);`, it reads bytes from the channel, and adds them *at the ByteBuffer’s current position.*  **The position is then updated to the index after the last byte added.**

So, here is your ByteBuffer’s state after first time you call channel.read:

```
Sending A Message....␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀
          1         2         3         4         5         6
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
                     ↑
                     position = 21
```

And here is your ByteBuffer’s state after the second time you call channel.read:

```
Sending A Message....Sending A Message....␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀
          1         2         3         4         5         6
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
                                          ↑
                                          position = 42
```

And here is your ByteBuffer’s state after the third time you call channel.read:

```
Sending A Message....Sending A Message....Sending A Message....␀␀␀␀␀␀␀
          1         2         3         4         5         6
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
                                                               ↑
                                                               position = 63
```

As you can see, the array always contains your original message.  **Do not use** `buffer.array()`; it ignores the buffer’s position.

After you read from a channel into a ByteBuffer, the correct way to obtain the data that was just placed in the ByteBuffer is to [flip](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#flip%28%29) it.  In the case of character data, you will then need to [decode](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#decode%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%29) it.

`flip()` will move the ByteBuffer’s position to the start of the ByteBuffer, so the next time you read from that ByteBuffer, you will be reading the data that was just placed into it by channel.read.

After channel.read:

```
Sending A Message....␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀
          1         2         3         4         5         6
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
                     ↑
                     position = 21
```

After `buffer.flip()`:

```
Sending A Message....␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀␀
          1         2         3         4         5         6
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
↑                    ↑
position = 0         limit = 21
```

If, after calling flip(), you were to call buffer.get(), it would read the byte `'S'` and would advance the ByteBuffer’s position by one.  If you don’t call flip(), the next attempt to read a byte would return 0, because that is the byte value at position 21.

But you do not want to read from the ByteBuffer directly;  you want to turn its contents into a String.  Currently, you are passing bytes to the String constructor, which is unwise—it will use the default character set.  If your server is running on Windows and the client is not running Windows (or vice versa), any non-ASCII characters will be corrupted.

The proper way to convert between bytes and characters is to use a [Charset](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html), specifically its [decode](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#decode%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%29) method.  Java defines several common Charsets in the [StandardCharsets](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) class.  Most of the time, [UTF-8](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#UTF_8) is the best choice.

So, using a standard Charset’s `decode` method looks like this:

```
channel.clear();
channel.read(buffer);
channel.flip();
String message = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(buffer).toString();
```

You need to set your ByteBuffer’s position back to zero for the next read, since you always want the next channel.read operation to place bytes at position 0 in the ByteBuffer.  The easiest way to do this is with ByteBuffer’s [clear()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#clear%28%29) method, as you can see in the code above.  clear() will also set the limit to the buffer’s current capacity (that is, the maximum allowed position).

Comment: Yes, the buffer can decode accordingly. However, it still can not fix the problem. Because the endless loop can not break because OP_READ event has not cleared, so the Selector always get the event there. You can try on your local.

Comment: I tried running it.  The server received one message, then a few empty messages, then exited.

Comment: hi VGR, remember to stop the client process. Then you will see a few empty messages. The point is, I assume that after consume the client, the Selector should not have the event any more. I mean, after consumption, selector.select(2000) should equal to 0. (because now no more client connect)

Comment: From [the documentation of SelectionKey.OP_READ](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/SelectionKey.html#OP_READ): “If the selector detects that the corresponding channel is ready for reading, has reached end-of-stream, has been remotely shut down for further reading, or has an error pending, then it will add `OP_READ` to the key's ready-operation set.”